# Android question about SQL Cursor and GROUP BY

Tags: java, sql, android, sqlite, cursor

I have a query that is making use of GROUP BY so that the results are grouped by a date column.  My question is this:

When I move through the cursor to get the results of the query, how can I get the multiple items associated with each group into my vector?  For example, I want to get BOTH "Item X" and "Item Y" for October 16, 2010.  Currently, I get them each separately.  Here is my code:

```
Vector<Event> v = new Vector<Event>();
Event e;

 detailCursor.moveToFirst();
 while (detailCursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
      e = new Event();
      e.setEventDate(detailCursor.getString(detailCursor
                .getColumnIndex("eventDate")));
      e.setItem(detailCursor.getString(detailCursor
                .getColumnIndex("Item")));

      v.add(e);

      detailCursor.moveToNext();
 }
detailCursor.close();
```

So, when I get the results from my Vector, I will get:

October 12, 2010
- Item X

October 12, 2010
- Item Y

and I want:

October 12, 2010 - Item X, Item Y

Yes, I do have to change my Vector to support multiple items, but hopefully you get what issue I'm facing...

Thanks!

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause is not supported in Android ICS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837544/android-ics-sqlite-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is provided by SQLite you need to change your query and use [GROUP_CONCAT(col)](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) in this case.

That will concat in one value all the subvalues for the same group.